# Are Parallel Streams and forkjoinpool safe to use in Production?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, production, forkjoinpool

We developed an API call which uses Java8 parallel streams and we have got very good performance, almost double compared to sequential processing when doing stress tests.

I know it depends on the use case, but I am using it for crypto operations, so I assume that this is a good use case.

However, I have read a lot of articles that encourages to be very careful with them. There are also articles that discuss that they are not very well internally designed, like [here](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html).

Thus: are parallel streams production ready; are they widely used in Production Systems?

Comment: The most systems in production i know are not even using java8.

Comment: @HenningLuther nor ours, but we want to move on. I suppose this should be a good thing

Comment: Why are you asking such a question when you already did *stress tests* on your own? I’d say, you are very likely using less tested JRE code without ever thinking about it…

Comment: @Holger I wouldn't have asked this question had not I read so many warnings about parallel streams online as I mentioned in the question. Also, as I have said below "I only tested it on testing server but I dont have the resources to mimic even part of the current production system to check is it working well on a large scale or not" I am not very experienced in my own to judge, that is why i asked

Comment: If by "safe", do you mean "Are the implementations reliable and well-tested", then Yes.  If you mean "can I shoot myself in the foot, get wrong answers, and get bad performance, by not following the rules or applying common sense?"  Also Yes.

Comment: By safe i mean, would i get any unwanted surprises ? Are there any successful production stories, there isnt any out there which makes you worried

Answer (score 5):

This question invites for "opinions"; but I try to answer fact-based.

### Fork/Join

These classes aren't new! As you can [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), they were already introduced with Java 1.7. In other words: these classes are around for several years by now; and used in many places. Thus: low risk.

### Parallel Streams

Were added "just recently" in Java terms (keep in mind how much of legacy Java has in 2017; and how slowly [compared to other languages] Java is evolving). I think the simple answer here is: we don't know yet if *parallel streams* will become a "cornerstone" of Java programming, or if people will prefer other ways to solve the problems addresses by parallel streams at some point.

Beyond that: users of other languages (such as JavaScript) are used to "changes gears" (aka frameworks) on an almost "monthly" basis. That is means a lot of churn, but it also means that "good things" are applied quickly; like in: why post-pone improving things?!

What I mean by that: *when* you find that parallel streams help you to improve performance; and *when* your team agrees "yes, we can deal with the stream()-way of writing code" ... then just go forward.

In other words: when parallel streams help your team/product to "get better", than why not try to capitalize on that? Now, not in 12 or 24 months.

If streams are "not that great big thing"; then well, maybe you have to rewrite some code at some point in the future.

Long story short: this is about balancing potential risks against potential gains. It seems that you made some positive experiences already; so I think a reasonable compromise would be: apply streams, but in a controlled way. So, that a later decision "wrong turn, get rid of them" doesn't become too expensive.

Comment: Totally agree, and that's part of the problem, there are doubts about parallel streams and what it can do to the servers, I only tested it on testing server but I dont have the resources to mimic even part of the current production system to check is it working well on a large scale or not. So I thought that someone might have already proceeded with that could give us a hint.

Comment: As per your last edit, that is what we are actually doing, we only re-implemented two calls from the whole system.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily go in and **change** large amounts of existing code. Use parallel streams for **new** code; and collect experiences.

Comment: The trigger to re-implement was lead by very low performance of current code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote the article you linked to I should say a few words.

As others have said, try it and see. Parallel Streams wants to split into a balanced tree: Split left, right, left, right. I you do that then performance is good. If not, then performance is terrible.

The Framework uses dyadic recursive division. Streams are linear. That is not a good match. And never forget that volume changes everything. Adding scaling to the mix may surprise you, but you won't know until you try it.

Let us know how it works out.